# How to get only one resut from =IMPORTXML "/GeocodeResponse//location" in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using
`=IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=A***s="&CONCATENATE(F17&", "&G17&", "&H17&", "&I17), "/GeocodeResponse//location")`

with google spreadsheet to geocode address to lat lon coordinates. And sometimes I get
`#REF! Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in J18`
As I understand there is more than one result and it needs 2 rows instead of 1. Is it possible to return only one result?
I tried using
`=IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=As="&CONCATENATE(F17&", "&G17&", "&H17&", "&I17), "/GeocodeResponse//location[1]")`
but sometimes it works and sometimes not.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the exact output or at least how it is represented and where the wanted data is located so I can adjust the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to see what is the output, and based on that, use `INDEX` function to pinpoint and filter the value returned

It would look like this if the data is in 2nd row, 1st column:
`=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=A***s="&CONCATENATE(F17&", "&G17&", "&H17&", "&I17), "/GeocodeResponse//location"), 2, 1)`

#### Reference:

- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

Comment: thanks,  this one works for me `=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=A***s="&CONCATENATE(F17&", "&G17&", "&H17&", "&I17), "/GeocodeResponse//location"),1,)` , and it is important to leave extra comma for row

Comment: Hi @SERG, I'm glad that it worked out for you.